# CamelCase for internal capital word

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, camelcasing

Sorry this might be a very meta question,
What should I name a variable with internal capitalized word? for example, `get FX rate`,

```
getFXrate?
getFxRate?
getFXRate?
```

Or is there some material I can read upon?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach is to use CamelCase only for abbreviations which are three characters ore more, for instance *GetXmlSchema*. In your example, however, where the abbreviation has only two characters, it would be the third alternative, *GetFXRate*.